# std::lock_guard won't unlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I'm trying to lock my list of mutexes in the following code so that only one thread can search it, unlock, lock or modify it at a time.

```
#include <mutex>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

struct MoveableMutex
{
    std::mutex m;
    MoveableMutex() {}
    MoveableMutex(MoveableMutex const&) {}
    MoveableMutex& operator = (MoveableMutex const&) { return *this; }
};

class Locks
{
    private:
        static std::mutex map_lock;
        static std::uint32_t lock_count;
        std::map<std::uint32_t, MoveableMutex> locklist;

    public:
        std::uint32_t AddLock();
        void RemoveLock(std::uint32_t ID);
        void Lock(std::uint32_t ID);
        bool TryLock(std::uint32_t ID);
        void Unlock(std::uint32_t ID);
};

std::uint32_t Locks::lock_count = 0;
std::mutex Locks::map_lock;

std::uint32_t Locks::AddLock()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(map_lock);
    locklist.insert(std::make_pair(++lock_count, MoveableMutex()));
    return lock_count;
}

void Locks::RemoveLock(std::uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(map_lock);
    auto it = locklist.find(ID);
    if (it != locklist.end())
    {
        it->second.m.unlock();
        locklist.erase(it);
    }
}

void Locks::Lock(std::uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(map_lock);
    auto it = this->locklist.find(ID);
    if (it != this->locklist.end())
    {
        it->second.m.lock();
    }
}

bool Locks::TryLock(std::uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(map_lock);
    auto it = this->locklist.find(ID);
    if (it != this->locklist.end())
    {
        return it->second.m.try_lock();
    }
    return false;
}

void Locks::Unlock(std::uint32_t ID)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(map_lock);
    auto it = this->locklist.find(ID);
    if (it != locklist.end())
    {
        it->second.m.unlock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Locks locklist;
    int i = locklist.AddLock();
    std::atomic<bool> stop(false);
    std::atomic<bool> stop2(false);

    std::thread o([&]
    {
        locklist.Lock(i);
        while(!stop)
        {
            std::cout << "Hey\n";
            Sleep(100);
        }
        locklist.Unlock(i);
    });

    std::thread t([&]
    {
        locklist.Lock(i);
        while(!stop2)
        {
            std::cout << "Hey2\n";
            Sleep(100);
        }
        locklist.Unlock(i);
    });

    Sleep(1000);
    stop = true;
    system("CLS");
    o.join();

    Sleep(1000);
    stop2 = true;
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

However, with the `std::lock_guard` inside the `Unlock` function, it causes a deadlock. If I remove the lock_guard from the Unlock function, it works fine.

Is there a reason the lock_guard isn't destructing or unlocking?

Comment: Well, you can always try using map_lock.lock()/map_lock.unlock() directly if you don't trust std::lock_guard. However, it appears that your problem stems from elsewhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One thread calls `Lock`, which ends up locking the mutex in the map. The other thread calls `Lock`, which locks `map_lock` then tries to lock the mutex in the map, and gets stuck there (with `map_lock` still held). Eventually, the first thread gets out of the loop and calls `Unlock`, which gets stuck waiting on `map_lock`.

The main design flaw here is that you have a thread acquire two locks, one after another. This only works safely if all threads acquire them **in the same order** (and release in reverse order of acquiring). But your code acquires them in different order at different times: that's a recipe for a deadlock.

See also: [lock hierarchy](http://www.drdobbs.com/parallel/use-lock-hierarchies-to-avoid-deadlock/204801163)